# How the Quotes enter between the URL written in the default.xml file?

Tags: magento2, layout, xml

I have created a block for the header. And it contains static page URLs. I have added the URLs from the Theme default.xml. Here is the code.

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="track-orders">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Track My Orders</argument>
        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="true">sales/guest/form</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

When I execute the file it shows the URL like below. What could be the issue?

```
<a href="https://test.com/"sales/guest/form"/">Track My Orders</a>
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to translate the path argument

Comment: Can you provide the block class code that you created to contains static page URLs.